# MathJax different in post vs. edit preview

Tags: bug, mathjax

This is a bit strange: in my answer [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/154139/111482), the MathJax has incorrect vertical alignment:

[image: Incorrect formatting]

But when I go to the edit page to try to fix it, the preview shows the correct formatting, different to what is shown in the post:

[image: Correct formatting]

But it's (of course) the same MathJax code, so this means either the MathJax renderer is wrong in the post or it is wrong in the preview. (I think it is wrong in the post.) In case it matters, I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: I actually see the reverse behavior. To me, the post itself appears to be formatted correctly (i.e. like the second image in this post), but the preview shown in the post editor appears to be formatted incorrectly (like the first image in this post). I'm using the regular post editor on MSE, not the Stacks editor (which you can opt in to using on MSE), in case that's relevant.

Comment: @V2Blast Curious!